# Replace xml in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm really new to SQL and I'm trying to replace a certain XML record with a brand new updated XML.

So i have a table that contains a list with records that all have a barcode ID, lets say barcode 123 has a column named XML that is filled with an XML A. I want to replace XML A with XML B that is saved on my hard drive.

Can anyone help me with this? It seems i can only find ways to directly replace data inside the xml itself, not replacing the entire XML.

I am using SQL server management studio 2012.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So do you want define a file name and update database with the contents of this file?

Comment: _"It seems i can only find ways to directly replace data..."_ Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Yes i want to replace an existing xml field with the contents from an xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an update query

```
update table_name set xml='all content of your xml file here' where BarcodeID=123;
```